# why vectors are defined as they are in analytic approach?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, vector-analysis

I am stuck in meaning of vectors I am reading ***Calculus by Apostol*** in which vectors are defined as n-tuple of numbers upto a **triple** of numbers it looked significant as it represented a ***direction and magnitude*** in space but why quadruple and other higher elements are considered vectors is still out of my thinking...

Please help me with this..

Comment: A vector in $\mathbb R^3$ is a list of three numbers. Often we need to work with much longer lists of numbers, such as lists of a thousand numbers or of a million numbers. For example a digital image can be viewed as a list of a few million numbers. It turns out that we can work with a list of a million numbers in much the same way that we can work with a list of three numbers, and that is useful.

Comment: @littleO you mean that vectors are used to represent more than direction and magnitude of something , can you give examples of more such things ,as an answer or any source which would help.

Comment: The answer lies within another question: why *shouldn't* we treat them the same?

Comment: Another example of how high dimensional vectors might arise, just picking something at random from engineering, you could have a plane flying around and every tenth of a second we get a measurement of the plane's acceleration and also angular velocity. That's six numbers, so a vector in $\mathbb R^6$. Maybe we have a bunch of other measurements too that we stick in the vector. Then we want to estimate the plane's position and orientation in real time.  That's another vector in $\mathbb R^6$ we want to estimate (and update the estimate every tenth of a second).

Comment: A list of numbers could be called either a point or a vector, depending on how we visualize it and what we do with it.   Maybe I should describe these lists of numbers I mentioned as "points" in a high dimensional space, but once we are working with points in a high dimensional space, we soon find ourselves thinking about vectors in that space, such as the displacement vector between two points.

Answer (score 0):

Higher dimensional problems arise very natural and the concepts of direction and magnitude, defined via a scalar product, can be used there as well.

Solving linear systems or linear optimization in $n$ variables are nice appplications.

Answer (score 0):

A line segment (with "magnitude and direction") between two points of space is   often called  an "geometric vector". The two points  may, respectively,be regarded as the argument and image of a  TRANSLATION.
 It is the  translation, (a function), which is the vector.... it satisfies the axioms of a vector space. 
2-3- n-Space may be turned into  vector spaces by addition and external multiplication. Translations on those sets may also be turned into (isomorphic) vector spaces by composition and external multiplication.

In general two points,  a and f(a), in the graph of some function ,f, generate, when visualised, line segments, whence "flow lines" and "vector fields".